# persistent preferences in android

Tags: android, persistence, android-preferences

I want to create a preference set which the user will not easily be able to delete/clean...
the idea i got is to create the persistence files in the public folder as and hidden folder (this way the files wont be deleted on unnistall or if the user asks for clean apps data)

my questions:

1- does anyone knows a better way? is it possible to do that using the apps private folder and somehow tag the files for no deletion?

2- is possible to use native android preferences framework and specify another file to store the properties? how?

3- does anyone know a good, SMALL and simple to use API for persistent properties similar to androids default?

Comment: Can't you create a hidden folder in android storage? It can't be seen easily. It wont be deleted if the user clears the app data. The best way would be to store the data in your own server instead of the local app.

Comment: @Pronoy999 what you mean by "android storage" ? i guess is the public storage that is what i meant in the text

Comment: Yes I meant public storage. I don't think there is any way to make a persistence shared preference storage. Can you please explain what are you actually trying to achieve?